# Azure Automation Runas Account insufficient privileges

Tags: azure, automation, azure-automation

I am trying to run the Get-AzADApplication cmdlet using azure automation.  I have checked all of my subscription and the Runas Account has "Contributer" in all of them.  I am still getting the following error though.  I know the error says insufficient privileges, but with the account having "Contributer" in all of my subscriptions, that just can't be true right?

Get-AzADApplication : Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
At line:41 char:21

- ```
  $Applications = Get-AzADApplication
  ```
- ```
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-AzADApplication], Exception
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ActiveDirectory.GetAzureADApplicationCommand

Here is the first little snippet of my code, and it just can't get past Get-AzADApplication

```
# Ensures you do not inherit an AzContext in your runbook
Disable-AzContextAutosave –Scope Process

$connection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name AzureRunAsConnection

while(!($connectionResult) -and ($logonAttempt -le 10))
{
    $LogonAttempt++
    # Logging in to Azure...
    $connectionResult = Connect-AzAccount `
                            -ServicePrincipal `
                            -Tenant $connection.TenantID `
                            -ApplicationId $connection.ApplicationID `
                            -CertificateThumbprint $connection.CertificateThumbprint

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
}

#Get Applications
$Applications = Get-AzADApplication
$ServicePrincipals = Get-AzADServicePrincipal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contributer role is not enough. You need administrator privilages.

The minumum role that you need is application administrator.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#application-administrator